# How to stop IntelliJ IDEA from creating new annotation processor profiles when a pom file is changed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-2, annotation-processing

I am using IntelliJ IDEA with Maven to write Java application. I have created several modules, created a custom annotation processor profile with a custom `Production sources directory` property and moved the modules to that profile. I have also enabled the setting that automatically imports the dependencies from the `pom.xml` file when they are added or changed.

The problem that I am facing is that whenever I change the `pom.xml` file, IntelliJ creates a new annotation processor profile for each module.
I have tried configuring the `Production sources directory` property for each new module, but they are returned to their default values when the pom is changed again. I have tried using the default profile instead of creating a custom one, but the result is the same.

How can I configure IntelliJ to stop changing the annotation processor profiles?

Comment: Have you considered configuring the APT via Maven facilities instead? You should be able to do that without Intellij-specific workarounds by passing correct arguments to Javac. Than just tell IntelliJ about the new source directory (does not matter if it is explicitly marked as generated code or not).

Comment: I am using dagger 2 for dependency injection and it automatically generates the code when I build the module or debug the code.